# Execute XML Source after script component completes in ssis

Tags: ssis

I want to execute the XML source after a script component is complete n SSIS data flow. i.e based on whether the script fails or passes the xml source flow should start (in the data flow). Is there any simpler way to do it.
I cannot create a connector because XML source doesn't have any inputs.

Comment: Got it, i can add a script task instead of script component in dataflow. And make a flow from script task to data flow. 
If there is anyother better way to do it. pleaes post, happy to mark that as a answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, i can add a script task instead of script component in dataflow. And make a flow from script task to data flow.